# Unity Visual Scripting doesn't expose the Physics Raycast Hit

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am forced to use Unity Visual Scripting because I am building for Microsoft Mesh. The Visual Scripting node for creating a Physics Raycast does not expose an output for the Hit object that the ray collides with, making it impossible for me to do anything with the result of the Raycast. Here's a screenshot of my node:
[image]

As you can see, I can't connect from the Raycast node to the `getDistance` node.

Comment: theres like 15+ raycasts, you need to pick the one with  more options. (eg the one with maxdistance)

Comment: I've tried them all. None of them expose the hit object as an output.

Comment: I think you're not reading them right https://imgur.com/nHTLfDy the HitInfo will get populated with it

Comment: That's really weird. None of my Raycast nodes have the HitInfo. I am using the Microsoft Mesh SDK so I wonder if they have blocked this on purpose.

Comment: i doubt it, but who knows.. tbh i hate visual scripting because the order and way you have to do many things is so unintiative when you know how to code.

Comment: I am a coder. I have to use VS for Mesh. They don't allow scripts for security. I am wondering wether they have stripped out the nodes that exposed the Hit. It's the only explanation. They use a subset of VS to prevent you from manipulating objects within their platform they don't want you messing with.

Comment: well thats just lame, it is possible the block it, it would seem odd though, but tbh im not going to download it to find out.. i dont need it.. can you still import your own code? if so you could expose it using your own code?